# Django query by foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am learning Django, and I have this basic model:

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    continent = models.ForeignKey('Continent')

class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    countries = ???
```

I want the Continent.countries attribute to return the matching countries, with continent-foreign key set to this continent. From Django docs I found that I should use foreign key, but the backward query is causing problems. I have experimented a few ways, but as a beginner I cant find the "correct" way of doing this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need to add a `countries` field in `Continent` model. To get all countries in a continent, you simply do `Continent.country_set.all()`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a `countries` attribute in `Continent` to establish a reverse relationship. You can find the `Countries` attached to each `Continent` by using the reverse `ForeignKey` relationship:

```
continent = Continent.objects.get(name='Asia')
countries = continent.country_set.all()
```

The `country_set` function is created by Django when you create a `ForeignKey` relationship between `Country` and `Continent`.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [xyres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925257/xyres). Also, you can define **related_name** in ForeignKey like:

```
continent = models.ForeignKey('Continent', related_name='countries')
```

so that, you can easily get countries in a continent:

```
continent.countries.all()
```

here, *continent* is object of the model Continent.